# Recognize laravel's relationships

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, relationship

I got 3 linked tables and i am quite lost with eloquent relationship.

I need help to recognize my relationship type. I use Laravel 4.1

*acquisitions* table :

```
#id
date
```

*sensors* table :

```
#id
name
```

*acquisition_sensor* table:

```
#id
acquisition_id
sensor_id
depth
value
```

Indeed 1 acquisition may have many depth, and different values.

I search a way to link my tables and use sensor model likee:

```
Sensor::find(1)->acquisitions->count();
```

and

```
Sensor::find(1)->sensor_acquisition->get();
```

I actually do it with the Query Builder but i think there is a way to use it more efficiently with eloquent !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to set up a many-to-many relationship in your Eloquent models.

**Sensor.php (model)**

```
public function acquisitions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Acquisition', 'acquisition_sensor', 'acquisition_id', 'sensor_id');
}
```

**Acquisition.php (modal)**

```
public function sensors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Sensor', 'acquisition_sensor', 'acquisition_id', 'sensor_id');
}
```

You can read more about many-to-many Eloquent relationships here, http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

---

If you want to run the eloquent query you described in your question, then you can do it like so:

```
Sensor::find(1)->acquisitions()->count();
```

If you are chaining, then make sure to add the `()` to acquisitions.

Comment: Ok. And how can i get, for exemple, all acquisition_sensor for a sensor ?

Comment: `$sensor = Sensor::find(1)->acquisitions;`

Comment: or you can do something like this `$sensor = Sensor::with('acquisitions')->first();`